# Cleaning a file name in Java

Tags: java, string, mp3, filenames, file-rename

I want to write a script that will clean my .mp3 files.
I was able to write a few line that change the name but I want to write an automatic script that will erase all the undesired characters `$%_!?7` and etc. while changing the name in the next format `Artist space dash Song`.

```
    File file = new File("C://Users//nikita//Desktop//$%#Artis8t_-_35&Son5g.mp3");
    String Original = file.toString();
    String New = "Code to change 'Original' to 'Artist - Song'";
    File file2 = new File("C://Users//nikita//Desktop//" + New + ".mp3");
    file.renameTo(file2);
```

I feel like I should make a list with all possible characters and then run the String through this list and erase all of the listed characters but I am not sure how to do it.

```
String test = "$%$#Arti56st_-_54^So65ng.mp3";
```

Edit 1:

When I try using the method `remove`, it still doesn't change the name.

```
String test = "$%$#Arti56st_-_54^So65ng.mp3";
System.out.println("Original: " + test);
test.replace( "[0-9]%#&\\$", "");
System.out.println("New:      " + test);
```

The code above returns the following output

```
Original: $%$#Arti56st_-_54^So65ng.mp3
New:      $%$#Arti56st_-_54^So65ng.mp3
```

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. A string is just an array of characters essentially. Have a list or another array with a collection of unwanted characters, loop through the string, check if the character at index is in the unwanted characters list, and remove. A regex would work too.

Comment: It may not be as simple as `s.replace( "[0-9]%#&\\$", "")` - what about "2000 Light Years from Home"? Or "10cc"?

Comment: It is - that's just the point. Look at OP's example - getting rid of digits seems to be one of the goals.

Comment: 50 Ways to Leave Your Lover - Paul Simon. Route 66 - The Rolling Stones. In the Year 2525 - Zager and Evans. 10.000 Men - Bob Dylan. 50,000 Miles Beneath My Brain - Ten Years After

Comment: @laune Even if I do the solution you did not suggest, it still doesn't work. I edited the question.

Comment: @tnw Can you give me an example please of how it should look like?

Comment: @Nik Don't do solutions I don't suggest. Read carefully.

Comment: @laune Yes, I know you did not suggest it. I just don't really understand why it didn't erase a thing.

Comment: :) I should have written `s.replace( "[0-9%#&$]", "")` but as it isn't useful I didn't guard myself sufficiently. Was trying to think up titles :)

Comment: Strangely enough, it still doesn't erase a thing :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest something like this:

```
public static String santizeFilename(String original){
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)-(.*)\\.mp3");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(original);

    if (m.matches()){
        String artist = m.group(1).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");
        String song = m.group(2).replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "");

        return String.format("%s - %s", artist, song);
    }
    else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Failed to match filename : "+original);
    }

}
```

(Edit - changed whitelist regex to exclude digits and underscores)

Two points in particular - when sanitizing strings, it's a good idea to whitelist permitted characters, rather than blacklisting the ones you want to exclude, so you won't be surprised by edge cases later.  (You may want a less restrictive whitelist than I've used here, but it's easy to vary)
It's also a good idea to handle the case that the filename doesn't match the expected pattern.  If your code comes across something other than an MP3, how would you like it to respond?  Here I've through an exception, so the calling code can catch and handle that appropriately.

Comment: Waht will happen to Terence Trent D'Arby?

Comment: It worked perfectly for the characters except `_` and the numbers. The output I receive is `Arti56st_-_54So65ng`. I tried adding `_` and numbers but with not success.

Comment: @laune Terence Trent D'Arby will be fine because I am planning on getting rid of all `'` anyway.

Comment: As I say, you could add extra characters you'd like not to be removed to the whitelist.  Personally I would prefer to remove apostrophes to be on the safe side, but if you like to live dangerously that's up to you!

Comment: But you can't get rid of digits - this would damage some titles. Unless you patch it up later.

Comment: @Nik: \w covers letters, numbers and underscores. If you'd like to remove those, replace the two whitelist parts with replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", "")  (Edited answer to make this change)

Comment: Great, thanks! I can't believe I haven't though about it before, but if for an example I will have multiple artists. Would it be possible referring to `&` as a separation and adding the second artist in the same way, or would it be just easier to erase whatever appears after `&`. And another thing. `_` will always be a desired `space`, so I can just use `replace` on that one, correct?

Comment: I guess that would depend on how the artists are combined in your filenames?  I'd suspect the presanitized versions will be in multiple formats, and you'll quickly get into the wonderful world of data quality.  It's worth asking how much benefit the added complexity is giving you in practice?  What proportion of cases would it match, how much code would you have to write/maintain, and will it actually improve your end user experience?  These problems tend to suffer from diminishing returns, particularly around edge cases.

Comment: About spaces - absolutely, but you probably want replaceAll.

Answer (score 0):

```
String new = original.replace( "[0-9]%#&\\$", "")
```

this should replace almost all the characters you don't want

or you can come up with your own regex

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: try something like this?
"/[^0-9,.]/"